# Shell scripts with table

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

I want to run a cron job monthly, weekly, daily but in everyday the hours and minutes will be changed as shown in the below table. So, how can I use a "for loop" to do this?

The hours and minutes will be updated according to the month.

```
1-Apr-2022  4:59    12:41   16:13   18:56   20:26
2-Apr-2022  4:58    12:40   16:13   18:57   20:27
3-Apr-2022  4:58    12:40   16:13   18:57   20:27
4-Apr-2022  4:55    12:40   16:13   18:58   20:28
5-Apr-2022  4:54    12:40   16:14   18:59   20:29
6-Apr-2022  4:52    12:39   16:14   19:00   20:30
7-Apr-2022  4:51    12:39   16:14   19:00   20:30
8-Apr-2022  4:49    12:39   16:14   19:01   20:31
9-Apr-2022  4:48    12:38   16:14   19:02   20:32
10-Apr-2022 4:47    12:38   16:14   19:02   20:32
11-Apr-2022 4:45    12:38   16:14   19:03   20:33
12-Apr-2022 4:44    12:38   16:14   19:04   20:34
13-Apr-2022 4:42    12:37   16:14   19:04   20:34
14-Apr-2022 4:41    12:37   16:14   19:05   20:35
```

Comment: The simplest way to align the cron with the call to prayer would be to control it in a shell script and have the cron job called every minute. If the current time is not a defined prayer time, then exit. If it is a defined time, perform an action. 

Comment: can you show me the syntax to how apply this way?

Comment: cron is really an *interval timer*; you may find that [at](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/at.1posix.html) is more suitable for non-interval time specifications. You could for example run a once-a-day cron job to read that day's timetable and create a sequence of  `at` jobs.

Comment: I've rolled back the post where the table is still included. The question does not make any sense without the timetable, so removing it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick little bash script that will check a file consisting of dates and times *in the same format as in the question* and echo out a line when matches are found:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/home/jason

CDATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
CTIME="$(echo -e "$(date +"%k:%M")" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')"

while IFS=' ' read -r line; do
    arr=($line)

    if [ "$CDATE" = "${arr[0]}" ]; then
        echo "Found Match! ${arr[0]}"
        for (( i=1; i<=${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
            if [[ ! -z "${arr[i]}" && "$CTIME" = "${arr[i]}" ]]; then
                echo "Time to call the ${arr[i]} prayer!"
            else
                echo "$CTIME does not match ${arr[i]}."
            fi
        done
    fi
done < "$DIR/times.txt"
```

For the sake of this example, let's assume this is written to a file named `call_prayer.sh`.

The script requires a second file named `times.txt`, which contains a list of dates and times in the exact same format as in the question:

```
{date} {time 1} {time 2} {time 3} {time 4} {time 5}
```

When run, the output of the above file will look something like this:

```
Found Match! 16-May-2022
Time to call the 5:03 prayer!
5:03 does not match 12:37.
5:03 does not match 16:14.
5:03 does not match 19:05.
5:03 does not match 20:35.
5:03 does not match .
```

<sup>**Note:** These prayer times are wrong, but that's fine as this is for illustration purposes only.</sup>

#### How this works

1. Get the current date and time in separate variables:

   ```
   CDATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
   CTIME="$(echo -e "$(date +"%k:%M")" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')"
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** `CTIME` has some extra bits to ensure there is no whitespace in the value. Using `%k` can result in  `3`, which is not the same as `3`, so trimming is important.</sup>
2. Read the contents of a file, line by line, and split the line into an array:

   ```
   while IFS=' ' read -r line; do
       arr=($line)
   ```
3. Compare the date at the start of the line with today's date. If there is a match, then continue:

   ```
   if [ "$CDATE" = "${arr[0]}" ]; then
   ```
4. Loop through each of the time values:

   ```
   for (( i=1; i<=${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** There is no hard rule that says each line must have 5 time values. This code here will read through as many as exists.</sup>
5. Compare the time value from the array to the current {hour}:{minute}.

   ```
   if [[ ! -z "${arr[i]}" && "$CTIME" = "${arr[i]}" ]]; then
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** The first part of this can probably be removed, as an empty string will never be the current time.</sup>.

   1. If the current time matches the array time, do something:

      ```
      echo "Time to call the ${arr[i]} prayer!"
      ```
   2. If the current time does not match the array time, do something:

      ```
      echo "$CTIME does not match ${arr[i]}."
      ```

      <sup>**Note:** There is no need to have this in the final code. It's just something to let you know the loop is working right now.</sup>
6. Complete the `while` statement and define where the file containing the prayer times exists:

   ```
   done < "$DIR/times.txt"
   ```

You can take this and customise it however you would like. Be sure to replace the source directory for the file (unless you and I share the same name) and replace the `echo` statements with actual actions that you would like to have happen when a prayer time is reached.

Remember to make the script file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x call_prayer.sh
```

---

**Disclaimer:** This code is free for you to use any way you wish, however, I offer no warranty nor promise to continue writing free code. This is to get you started and, hopefully, encourage you to develop new skills.

Comment: can i to do this with loop to run the script once a day and execute something while the current time match with time in the table ?

Comment: You can do whatever you’d like, but that would require you to add a whole lot more code to handle situations where the loop prematurely quits, consumes too many resources, or is just an otherwise poor use of resources. Cron jobs can run every minute, so this solution fits within that particular case. How you reach your goal is up to you 